# How to redirect a url with order number to other path

Tags: .htaccess

I want to write a 301 redirect that redirects all the requests from this domain + order id goes to an other domain

56953 is an order id which is variable

my RewriteBase is a subfolder

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /OXM
```

subdomain.domain1.co.uk/transaction=56953

To

subdomain.domain2.co.uk/work/transaction/56953

Comment: subdomain.domain1.co.uk/transaction=56953

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^transaction=(\d{5})$ http://subdomain.domain2.co.uk/work/brief/$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Thank you @anubhava. But I want to be implemented only on transaction page

Comment: I'm getting /OXM/transaction=OBE56953 was not found on this server. error I think because my RewriteBase is /OXM

Comment: Sorry about that. I wouldn't think that would cause problem. subdomain.domain1.co.uk/OXM/transaction=56953 That i want to redirect it to subdomain.domain2.co.uk/work/transaction/56953

Comment: I've done simple redirection on pages by RewriteRule ^transactions/?$ http://subdomain.domain2.co.uk/transactions/ [R=301,L] --- and it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66215/discussion-between-anubhava-and-isaac-rajaei).